# Java runnable doesn't seem to be triggered in Android

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have a very simple test application I'm making, and to set the seekBar's position I'm using a runnable. Although I have very little experience with actually working with a runnable.

```
public class MySpotify extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private SeekBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spotify_app);
        myProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.myBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myProgress.setProgress(25);
    }
}
```

If I move `myProgress.setProgress(25);` into the onCreate then it works. But I want it to be set off in the runnable. Any ideas?

Comment: Something must run the `Runnable`. This can be a separate thread, the method `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or a direct call to `run()`

Comment: As @MichaelButscher said, it needs to be started by someone. either new Thread(new MySpotify()).start(), runOnUIThread(new MySpotify()) or myProgress.post(new MySpotify()). You should read about Threads and rethink your design, it really makes no sense to have a whole Runnable Class to update the progress. You could even have a normal Activity Class and something like myProgress.post(new Runnable(){public void run(myProgress.setProgress(25))}); or new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(myProgress.setProgress(25))}).start();

Answer (score 0):

You need to `post()` a `Runnable` to a `Thread` for it to execute. Try calling `post(this);` inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: post on a View. myProgress.post(this)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spotify_app);
    myProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.myBar);

    myProgress.post(new Runnable()
    {       
        public void run()
        {
            myProgress.setProgress(25);
        }
    });
}
```

You need something to run the `post()` method on

Comment: My application seems to throw a not responding window now. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set any breakpoints to see if it gets past that point or if its stuck there? I don't believe that code should have given you that. Although, I don't use `Runnable`s often. I normally use `AsyncTask` if I need something like this.

Comment: I didn't set any breakpoints, but yeah If I leave it running for like 30 seconds, then I get the not responding dialog.

Comment: But you should set a breakpoint and debug the code to see where it gets stuck. Is this all of your code? If not then you aren't doing anything to end this

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34880/discussion-between-eghdk-and-codemagic)

Answer (score 0):

You can start the run method by just calling run();
Be aware that it will execute on the main thread.
Also be aware that it will run only once since there is no loop.

if you want to update while doing something else you sjould create a new thread.

example:

```
public class MySpotify extends Activity{

    private SeekBar myProgress; //I asume it is call "myProgress" instead of "progress"

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spotify_app);
        myProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.myBar);

        ThreadExample example = new ThreadExample();
        example.start();
        /* Start a new thread that executes the code in the thread by creating a new thread.
         * If ou call example.run() it will execute on the mainthread so don't do that.
         */
    }

    private class ThreadExample extends Thread{
        public void run() {
            myProgress.setProgress(25);
        }                    
    }
}
```